# Django model design basics

Tags: django, model

I have two models status_message,comment each has a id,text(and some extra fields) each status can have many comments
I need one more model called likes. status_message and comment can have many likes.what should be the correct model for the likes?

1)a "type" field for finding whether likes is for a status_message or a comment, and common field  "postid" for id of status_message,comment

or

2)separate status_message_id,comment_id and each with null option true

My requirement includes - find out status_message,comment details with their like counts .what should be the correct design?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, each "status" can have "comments" and each "comment" can have "likes".

So why are you not doing the same thing that you do between status and comment with comment and likes ?

I means by that in the comment referencing the status with a ForeignKey and in the likes referencing the comment with a ForeignKey.

Like that you can get all the comment for a specific status and also all the likes.

Example:

```
status:
  id
  text
comment:
  id
  text
  statusId (foreignKey ref status.id)
likes:
  id
  commentId (foreignKey ref comment.id can be null)
  statusId (foreignKey ref status.id can be null)
```

I thing for django it is the solution

Comment: both status and comment can have likes